# Turn abbreviated months in 4 different languages into corresponding month number

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have English, German, French and Spanish abbreviations of months and I must return it as a number

so 'dic' would be 12 //es

or 'avr' would be 4 //fr

I also have the locale that would be used

This is what the inputs looks like

```
<?php return array (
'de' => array (
    'Jan' => 'Jan',
    'Feb' => 'Feb',
    'März' => 'Mar',
    'Apr' => 'Apr',
    'Mai' => 'May',
    'Juni' => 'Jun',
    'Juli' => 'Jul',
    'Aug' => 'Aug',
    'Sep' => 'Sep',
    'Okt' => 'Oct',
    'Nov' => 'Nov',
    'Dez' => 'Dec',
),
'es' => array(
    'ene' => 'Jan',
    'feb' => 'Feb',
    'mar' => 'Mar',
    'abr' => 'Apr',
    'may' => 'May',
    'jun' => 'Jun',
    'jul' => 'Jul',
    'ago' => 'Aug',
    'sept' => 'Sep',
    'oct' => 'Oct',
    'nov' => 'Nov',
    'dic' => 'Dec',
),
'fr' => array(
    'janv' => 'Jan',
    'Feb' => 'Feb',
    'mars' => 'Mar',
    'avr' => 'Apr',
    'mai' => 'May',
    'juin' => 'Jun',
    'juil' => 'Jul',
    'aout' => 'Aug',
    'sept' => 'Sep',
    'oct' => 'Oct',
    'nov' => 'Nov',
    'dec' => 'Dec',
),
);
```

I have been messing around with

```
setLocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE.UTF-8)
//"de_DE.UTF-8"
echo  strftime("%A %d %B %Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 22, 1978));
//"Freitag 22 Dezember 1978"
```

I am using Carbon to parse the date i.e.

```
\Carbon::parse('Jan');
```

will give me

```
 Carbon\Carbon {#1866
 +"date": "2018-01-18 00:00:00.000000",
 +"timezone_type": 3,
 +"timezone": "UTC",}
```

I want to be able to do the same with the other languages.

Comment: Not much related to answer, but I would go with array structure like `[ 'Jan' => [ 'de' => 'Jan', 'es' => 'ene', 'fr' => 'janv' ], 'Feb' => [ 'de' => 'Feb', 'es' => 'feb', 'fr' => 'feb' ] ]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$month = array_search('März', array_keys($months['de'])) + 1;
now()->month($month);
```

This will give you:

```
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1521374393 {#871
    date: 2018-03-18 11:59:53.0 UTC (+00:00),
}
```